# How to get MVC to ignore undefined sections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC 3 if you define a section in a view that isn't defined in the layout you get an exception thrown.  Is there a way mark the section option from the **view** ?

Comment: Why would you have a section in a view that is not defined in the layout - if you are going to ignore it, why is it there?  If this is a DRY issue, you should probably break your view into partials...

Comment: @Tommy I agree that id doesn't make sense to have sections that aren't defined in the layout.  I'm just curious if anyone has come up with a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render a section in a view that is not defined in the layout.

You can assume like *layout is an abstract class* and *view is a concrete implementation*. The section defined in layouts are nothing but abstract methods that will be implemented in views.

So adding a section in view that is not defined in layout is kind of implementing an abstract method that even not exists. And if you define a section in a view it is like adding an abstract method to a concrete class and that changes the view into a layout. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is an overload for `RenderSection` method that takes second parameter which defines whether the section is required:

```
@RenderSection("javascript", false)
```

Comment: this would be in the layout, not the view.  His question is the opposite, the section is defined in the view, but no placeholder in the layout (I think)

Comment: This is from the Layout page, I'm talking from the View'

Comment: I got it, but why not put this string into your layout? If you will not define it later it will just render nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
@RenderSection("SomeSection", false)
@if (!IsSectionDefined("SomeSection")) { }
```

The second part is not necessary, but if you want to do sometheing by default if it is not available.